# Losing DNS when connecting via pptp vpn from a Windows client to a Linux server

Tags: linux, windows, domain-name-system, vpn, pptp

I setup pptp on my Linux (CentOS) server. When I connect from a Windows client
I am losing name service on the windows side. Connecting to my application works
ok, though.

I tried to set ms-dns in option-pptp and also to set a DNS server on the windows side, but
to no avail.

Thanks for any ideas, Michael

Answer (score 1):

After you bring up the VPN, run ipconfig /a to see what you computer is using for the DNS server. Are you setup to use the default gateway on the remote host? If you turn that off, then only packets going to the CenOS Server network will go though the PPTP connection. All other packets will go out your regular connection. Then you can continue to use your existing DNS servers (and it will make browsing faster as well).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a WINS server on your network then you should also add the ms-win option to your configuration.

Also make sure you're also setting the domain.  Otherwise the search domain for resolving names may not append the appropriate domain name for dns to work unless people use the fully qualified domain name.